# Sending object, int and String via socket, serialisation

Tags: java, serialization

so I have a PrintWriter and a ObjectOutputStream trying to send an int, String and a Color[] from the client when the user clicks the list, where 'out' is the PrintWriter and outObject is the ObjectOutputStream.

```
private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener{
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
      if(e.getSource() == list){
          int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());   ///get the game that the player has selected          
          try{
              out.println(index);
                              out.println("hel");
                              Color[] colors = new Color[5];
                              outObject.writeObject(colors)
          }
}
```

Server, where 'in' is a scanner, 'objectIn' is an objectInputStream :

```
                while(true)
                    if(in.nextLine().equals("hel")){
                    System.out.println("fee");
                }
                else if(in.hasNextInt()){
                    System.out.println("dee");
                }
                Object o = objectIn.readObject();
                if(o instanceof Color[]){
                    System.out.println("ree");
                }
```

If i try to send all three, on the first click the server only registers the String, and then all clicks after the server only registers the int, never registering the Color[], if i send the int first, then the Color[] and then the int like :`

```
                              out.println(index);
                              Color[] colors = new Color[5];
                              outObject.writeObject(colors);
                              out.println("hel");
```

Only the int and Object are registered first, on the second click only the String and then subsequent clicks only the int.
`

```
                Object o = objectIn.readObject();
                if(in.nextLine().equals("hel")){
                    System.out.println("fee");
                }
                //Object o = objectIn.readObject(); 
                else if(in.hasNextInt()){
                    System.out.println("dee");
                }
                else if(o instanceof Color[]){
                    System.out.println("ree");
                    o = null;
                }
```

If I use the above series of if statements nothing is registered

Using the first series of if statements, if i try to send the Color[] on it's own it's not registered, but if I send it with an int both are registered.
If i try to send the String and the Color[], sending the String first like so :

```
              out.println("hel");
              Color[] a = new Color[5];
              outObject.writeObject(a);
```

both are registered once and then never again, also in the opposite way than was expected i.e the Color[] was registered first and then the String; if i send both but the Color[] first and then the String neither are registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `out` object (which is a `PrintWriter`) wraps the `outObject` object, which is the `ObjectOutputStream`. You should not use both a `PrintWriter` and a `ObjectOutputStream` for the same underlying connection. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113460/objectoutputstream-and-printwriter-conflict) for more details.

Comment: I assume a scanner would interfere with with an objectinputstre as we'll ?,not that I would want one without the printwriter